# Why does 'Search Question' of the Answers module not show any results?

Tags: views, 7

The "Search Questions" view page which is provided by the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module does not show any results. I am pasting the typed question as it is yet it just shows "No questions match".

What could be the issue?

**Edit**: I did get the solution just now, I was trying other related modules [Best Answer](https://www.drupal.org/project/best_answer) and [Answers Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/aup) and after enabling them the Search feature started working. Probably some other module which is mutual between them gets enabled and start working, But I could not figured it out, as the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module list was showing all dependency modules enabled prior to all this. Any way it start working.

Comment: Have you tried playing with its options a bit? Setting the algorithm a bit manually to make it more flexible?

Comment: I did got the solution just now, I was trying other related modules [Best Answer](https://www.drupal.org/project/best_answer) and [Answers Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/aup) and after enabling them the Search feature started working. probably some other module which is mutual between them is gets enabled and start working, But I could not figured it out, as Answers module list was showing all dependency modules enabled prior to all this. Any way it start working. Will figure out after uninstalling all and if found will raise a issue on module page. Thanks

Comment: How did you get a "search questions" feature? My installation of answers didn't come with anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Comment #1 in issue 1619676](https://www.drupal.org/node/1619676#comment-6086840), which states:

> One hypothesis: have you run cron?
>
> The way content gets indexed is during cron runs ... not immediately when new content is created.

It could well be that "in the meantime" cron was run, which would explain why "*... the Search feature started working...*" (as in your comment).

Disclosure; I'm a co-maintainer of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module.

Comment: `run cron`, could be the reason, as I installed other module, I did run cron afterward. Thanks